# How grunt-scss-lint can exclude some files or directory?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, scss-lint

I am using grunt-scss-lint with sucess.

but I wanna exclude a folder or files, but after runt he task still catching the folder, any idea how to exclude the file or directory?

in the docs says:

```
exclude

Type: String or Array
Default: null
Exclude one or more files from being linted.
```

**grunt task**

```
scsslint: {
        allFiles: [
          'scss/_main.scss',
        ],
        options: {
          config: 'scss/.scss-lint.yml',
          reporterOutput: '.tmp/scss-lint-report.xml',
          colorizeOutput: true,
          compact:false,
        },
        exclude: [
            'scss/vendor/font-awesome/font-awesome.scss'

          ]
      },
```

any ideas?

**Update:**

fixed moving exclude to the options.

```
scsslint: {
            allFiles: [
              'scss/_main.scss',
            ],
            options: {
              config: 'scss/.scss-lint.yml',
              reporterOutput: '.tmp/scss-lint-report.xml',
              colorizeOutput: true,
              compact:false,
              exclude: [
                'scss/vendor/font-awesome/font-awesome.scss'

              ]
            }
          },
```

Comment: Should not the `exclude` config be _inside_ of `options`?

Comment: yes :), can your answer the question? so I can give to you some points, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes. I have added my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exclude` configuration must be moved to within the `options` object:

```
options: {
    config: 'scss/.scss-lint.yml',
    reporterOutput: '.tmp/scss-lint-report.xml',
    colorizeOutput: true,
    compact:false,
    exclude: [
        'scss/vendor/font-awesome/font-awesome.scss'
    ]
},
```